# What is the point of Export as Xcode Archive in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

What can I do with it if I export it?

Comment: You can re-import it and be where you were before.

Comment: I use it to transfer an archive from my main computer to a laptop when needed.

Comment: It can also be used to make separate backups.

Comment: How do I import it? I couldn't find this option.

Comment: RIght I double click it haha